# Creating a gradient border for non-div element

Tags: html, css, web

i have bordered button (Non-div element, ). I need to get gradient color on the borders of my button. Now my button looks like this (In generally this is it):

```css
.uibutton, uibutton:focus {
  width: 120px;
  height: 27px;
  color: #007AFF;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #007AFF;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.uibutton:active {
  width: 120px;
  height: 27px;
  color: #007AFF;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.uibutton:disabled {
  width: 120px;
  height: 27px;
  color: #C7C7CC;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C7C7CC;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="uibutton">Hello World</button>
<button class="uibutton" disabled>Hello World</button>
```

I need gradient only in borders of button.
I'm so sorry, i'm idiot, just i confused in my code and how to write it.
Thanks for patience.

Comment: You can just assign the class xx to the button.

Comment: Did you try it and, if so, what was the issue. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LkrkBd?editors=1100#0

Comment: I think you need to look at this URL..it seems your question with your pic is on this site with a solution http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/

Comment: i'm sorry, but i asked wrong. I don't need button like this. I'm just need to get gradient on button. So, wait a minute, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add gradient background to button use code above or try [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

```css
.button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 27px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.solid {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #3acfd5 0%,#3a89d5 50%,#3a51d5 100%);
}

.thin {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #1AD6FD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1D62F0;
  
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1px 100%;
  
  background-color: transparent; /* removes button background */
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #1AD6FD 0%, #1D62F0 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #1AD6FD 0%, #1D62F0 100%);
}
```

```html
<button class="button solid">My button</button>
<button class="button thin">My button</button>
```

Comment: @JakiHappyCity Do you want to have one-pixel gradient borders?

Comment: Please wait a minute. I'm editing my thread, and i think thats done. But yes, i need 1px gradient borders with border-radius: 3px;
P.S. Done thread :)

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me